# Space complexity of reassigning an array

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

What is the space complexity of the following Java code?

```
public int[] foo(int[] x) {
   x = new int[x.length];
   // Do stuff with x that does not require additional memory
   return x
}
```

Is it O(1) or O(N)? I've seen both answers. But I can't understand how it could be O(1). I would guess that it's O(N). We create a new array of the same size while the original array might still exist. Thus the original array is not replaced, i.e. we allocated additional storage space that increases linear with the length N of the input array. Am I correct?

Comment: First of all, you comment about creating a new array the same size as the original violates the comment about doing stuff that does not require additional memory.  Secondly, it is not possible to determine the complexity of '**stuff**'.

Comment: In the first place, what is N ?

Comment: @itprorh66: I don't see that the code was updated since your comment, so as the comment comes *after* the allocation, there is no contradiction, and also the OP guarantees that 'stuff' does not require additional memory.

Comment: Space complexity refers to memory *in addition to* the memory used to hold the input. So the question is, can we reuse the memory used to pass `x`? That depends on a number of things, mostly regarding whether `x` is a reference to the argument or a copy, and whether assigning to `x` allow the reuse of the memory used by the argument.

Comment: @itprorh66 Sorry if the comment lead to confusion but as Yves Daoust pointed out the comment comes after the allocation. So I don't see any contradiction.  And the question about the space complexity relates exclusively to the allocation line. I only included the comment as a placeholder for the original code since it's completely irrelevant for my question. Again, my question relates only to the initial allocation. After the initial allocation no more memory is allocated.

Comment: @Yves Daoust refers to the length of the input array x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantic of this piece of code is unsure, as the language is not specified. In any case, O(1) isn't possible because one allocates a new array at the same time that the original exists. (In a garbage collected language, one could imagine, with a lot of bad faith, that x is deallocated then immediately reallocated at the same place.)

Comment: It needn't be a garbage collected language, C has the function `realloc` that explicitly has this behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I don't see any realloc in this code.

Comment: A language was never specified for this question.  It could be that C is the only language that has realloc.

Comment: @MarkRansom: if that was C, the compiler would not use realloc, as the input x must be kept.

Answer (score 0):

`O(N)` with details that are highly dependent on various external factors such as your operating system.

A naive implementation requires actually zeroing out memory and assigning it.  If the space requested is small, and particularly if you've already freed a good place to put it, this is probably what is going to happen.  That operation is `O(N)`.

If the space requested is large, you're probably just going to set up page table entries and NOT allocate any space.  This is again `O(N)`, but with extremely good constants.  As you use the memory it actually has to get assigned, which is no faster than doing it up front.  (It is actually slower.)  But, in the meantime, being slow to use up memory is good for reducing contention on RAM.

Comment: The question is about *space* complexity. It is Θ(N).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah, missed the "space" bit.  In the page table entries version, the space actually taken has very small constants - just a data structure per page saying how to page it in if you were to try to access it.

Comment: Usually, complexity analysis does not care about the mundane details of memory allocation and mapping. The computational model is RAM. Exactly N integers and a pointer would be counted.

Comment: Usually, complexity analysis does not care about the mundane details of memory allocation and mapping. The computational model is RAM. Exactly N integers and a pointer would be counted. We don't have realistic models that are 1. sufficiently representative of modern computers and 2. tractable.